# Alarm During Specific time Android Application

Tags: java, android, alarm

Can anyone inform me how can I create an alarm in android application that starts from current time  and it'll be repeated for each 10 minutes during specific time?

For example, depending on different cases the time that the  alarm should repeate is during 2 hours, another case it might be just 1:30 hour and so on.

Is there any way to do that?

Actually I used a code I took it from the web, as shown below:

public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onDestroy();

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        Toast.makeText(this, "...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BroadcastReceiver and an PendingIntent. First you declare an BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class EventAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private long alarmTime;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent1) {

    //declare the new time for the alarm, you can use a time stamp, for example in the next hour
    alarmTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+(60*60000); 

            //set an intent to the Receiver
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, EventAlarmReceiver.class);

             //set an PendingIntent to the Intent
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

            //add to the System Alarm Manager
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
}
```

}

and start the alarm in the Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, EventAlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)   getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, time, pendingIntent);
```